# Basemap: Get all data points on colorbar which each point refelecting the ploted color

Tags: python, pandas, plot, matplotlib-basemap

I have a dataset, containing different types of trees in numerical i.e

```
Types = 4,8,9,10,13,15,19,33
```

I am plotting these types on a scatter plot, each type being represented by a different color. I can't figure out a way for the color bar to represent the data correctly. So that it looks like this.

[image]

The color bar ticks should only represent the data plotted with each color representing a type. i.e

Green = 4
Orange = 8
etc

The plot below is my failed attempt at doing this. The colorbar ticks do not represent the vegetation plotted but a  range.

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))
m=Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=25,llcrnrlon=-130,urcrnrlat=49,urcrnrlon=-104.5,resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawstates()
x,y=m(list(Y60['col']),list(Y60['row']))
m.scatter(x,y,c=Y60['potveg'],s=Y60['potveg']*5,cmap='Dark2')
cbar=plt.color bar()
```

[image: Types ploted]

Thanks

Comment: If you have distinct numeric values, then you need to make your own custom colormap.  Either that, or map your types to 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7.

Comment: @TimRoberts, how can I create a custom color map in this case? The expected leged should look like the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer focuses on the steps to create the legend. Read the comments in the code for explanation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Each item of legends requires 3 propereties: color/label_text/marker_shape
colors = ["green", "orange", "purple", "red", "lightgreen", "gray"]
texts = ["4", "9", "13", "15", "19", "33"]
markers = ["o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"]
len0 = len(colors)

# Points' locations and attributes
xs = [3,2,4,5,4,2,7,3]
ys = [41,12,32,15,35,21,23,43]
colors1 = ["green", "orange", "purple", "red", "lightgreen", "gray", "green", "orange"]
texts1 = ["4", "9", "13", "15", "19", "33", "4", "9"]
markers1 = ["o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"]
sizes1 = [8,16,9,12,7,4,10,6]
len1 = len(xs)

# Plot `none` data point and 
#  save the output patches objects for legend making
patches0 = [ plt.plot([],[], marker=markers[i], ms=8, ls="", mec=None, color=colors[i], 
          label="{:s}".format(texts[i]) )[0]
          for i in range(len0) ]
# Plot point data
# Demo data is used here
for i in range(len1):
    plt.plot(xs[i], ys[i], marker=markers1[i], ms=sizes1[i], color=colors1[i])

# Plot legend in the upper-right corner
plt.legend(handles=patches0, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), title="Potveg", 
                   loc='upper right', ncol=1, facecolor="lightgray", numpoints=1 )
plt.show()
```

[image: plot1]

**Edit1**

Since the data has categories and quantities information to render on the plot, my answer is not complete without handling both of them.

The code to produce 2 legends on a single plot is not straight forward as one may think.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# For `Categories` symbol
# ----------------
# Each item of legends requires 3 propereties: color/label_text/marker_shape
color_V = ["green", "orange", "purple", "red", "lightgreen", "gray"]
text_V = ["4", "9", "13", "15", "19", "33"]
marker_V = ["o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"]
len_V = len(color_V)

# For `Size/quantities` symbol
# --------------------
color_S = ["gray", "gray", "gray", "gray"]
sizes_S = [4, 8, 12, 16]         #increasing values ...
text_S = ["4", "8", "12", "16"]  # cover `sizes1` below
marker_S = ["o", "o", "o", "o"]  #use disk shape
len_S = len(color_S)

# Data locations and attributes
xs = [3,2,4,5,4,2,7,3]
ys = [41,12,32,15,35,21,23,43]
colors1 = ["green", "orange", "purple", "red", "lightgreen", "gray", "green", "orange"]
texts1 = ["4", "9", "13", "15", "19", "33", "4", "9"]
markers1 = ["o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"]
sizes1 = [8,16,9,12,7,4,10,6]
len1 = len(xs)

# Plot `none` data point and 
#  save the output patches objects for legend making
patches_V = [ plt.plot([],[], marker=marker_V[i], ms=8, ls="", color=color_V[i], \
          label="{:s}".format(text_V[i]) )[0] \
          for i in range(len_V) ]

# Do it again for another legend
patches_S = [ plt.plot([],[], marker=marker_S[i], ms=sizes_S[i], ls="", \
        color=color_S[i], \
        label="{:s}".format(text_S[i]) )[0] for i in range(len_S) ]

# Plot point data
# Demo data is used here
for i in range(len1):
    plt.plot(xs[i], ys[i], marker=markers1[i], ms=sizes1[i], color=colors1[i])

# Plot 1st legend in the upper-right corner
first_legend = plt.legend(handles=patches_V, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), title="Categories", 
                   loc='upper right', ncol=1, facecolor="lightgray", numpoints=1 )

# Need to freeze first legend to enable addition of the second legend by ...
# Add the legend manually to the current Axes
plt.gca().add_artist(first_legend)

# Then we can add the second legend normally
plt.legend(handles=patches_S, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1), title="Sizes", 
                   loc='upper left', ncol=1, facecolor="lightgray", numpoints=1 )


plt.show()
```

[image: twolegend]

Answer (score 1):

Since it is possible to post live code that the readers can run and get the results, I offer another answer here.

I know that `pyodide` package and related libraries that need to load and run may not work in all devices. Therefore, user's feedback is welcome.

```js
async function main() {
  let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
  console.log(
    pyodide.runPython(`
        import sys
        sys.version #for ref uses
    `)
  );
  await pyodide.loadPackage(["matplotlib"]);
pyodide.runPython(`
# Careful about the indenting
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("module://matplotlib.backends.html5_canvas_backend") #causes minor error, but works
#import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.cm as cm

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
      
# For Categories symbol
# ---------------------
# Each item of legends requires 3 properties: color/label_text/marker_shape
color_V = ["green", "orange", "purple", "red", "lightgreen", "gray"]
text_V = ["Class4", "Class9", "Class13", "Class15", "Class19", "Class33"]
marker_V = ["o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"]
len_V = len(color_V)

# For Size/quantities symbol
# --------------------------
color_S = ["gray", "gray", "gray", "gray"]
sizes_S = [4, 8, 12, 16]         # increasing values for symbols
text_S = ["4", "8", "12", "16"]  # covers sizes1 below, for symbols
marker_S = ["o", "o", "o", "o"]  # dot shape
len_S = len(color_S)

# Data (scatter type) and attributes
xs = [3,2,4,5,4,2,7,3,5]
ys = [41,12,32,15,35,21,23,43,40]
colors1 = ["green","orange","purple","red","lightgreen","gray","green","orange","green"]
#class_number1 = ["4", "9", "13", "15", "19", "33", "4", "9", "4"]
markers1 = ["o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o"]
sizes1 = [8,16,9,12,7,4,10,6,14]
len1 = len(xs)

# Plot none data point and 
#  save the output patches objects for category-data symbols
patches_V = [ plt.plot([],[], marker=marker_V[i], ms=8, ls="", color=color_V[i], \
          label="{:s}".format(text_V[i]) )[0] \
          for i in range(len_V) ]

# Do it again for another legend
#   save the output patches objects for quantity-data symbols
patches_S = [ plt.plot([],[], marker=marker_S[i], ms=sizes_S[i], ls="", \
        color=color_S[i], \
        label="{:s}".format(text_S[i]) )[0] for i in range(len_S) ]

# Plot scatter-point data
# Demo data is used
for i in range(len1):
    plt.plot(xs[i], ys[i], marker=markers1[i], ms=sizes1[i], color=colors1[i])

# Plot 1st legend in the upper-right corner
first_legend = plt.legend(handles=patches_V, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), title="Categories", \
                   loc='upper right', ncol=1, facecolor="lightgray", numpoints=1 )

# Need to freeze first legend to enable addition of the second legend by ...
plt.gca().add_artist(first_legend)

# Then we can add the second legend normally
plt.legend(handles=patches_S, bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1), title="Sizes", \
                   loc='upper left', ncol=1, facecolor="lightgray", numpoints=1 )
plt.show()
`);
}
main();
```

```html
<h3>Pyodide test run</h3>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.20.0/full/pyodide.js"></script>
```